# kendo-ui-angular2 panelbar expande only on arrow click

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Is it possible to select an item without expanding/collapsing it, then expand/collapse it only when the arrow is clicked?

```
<kendo-panelbar  [items]="myItems" [selectable]="true (stateChange)="stateChange($event)">
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show what have you tried and with detailed description, please. Thanks

Comment: Improve English